# Não consigo encontrar o erro nessa simples questão de programação em javascript na qual preciso verificar quantas vezes a letra "o" aparece na frase

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
    var frase = "The Lord of The Rings";

    var letra = "o";

    function vezesLetraAparece(frase, letra) {
      var resultado = 0;
      var indice;

      for (indice = 0; indice < frase.lenght; indice++) {
       if (letra === frase[indice]) {
        resultado ++;
          }
       }
      return resultado;
    }
```

Comment: `frase.lenght` => `frase.length` - Voce escreveu `length` errado...

Comment: E também esqueceu de chamar a função! :-)

Answer (score 0):

"length" está escrito errado.

E também não está usando a função em outro lugar para exibir o resultado.